# copy_from_user fails with write error : bad address

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I am writing a test kernel module to simulate locks/unlocks. Below is the code :

```
#define MODULE_NAME "lock_injection"
#define COMMAND_BUF_SIZE 128

static DEFINE_MUTEX(my_mutex);
static DEFINE_SPINLOCK(my_spinlock);
static int irq_disabled = 0;

static char command_buf[COMMAND_BUF_SIZE];

// Function to execute the commands
static void execute_command(const char *command) {
    if (strcmp(command, "lock_mutex") == 0) {
        mutex_lock(&my_mutex);
    } else if (strcmp(command, "unlock_mutex") == 0) {
        mutex_unlock(&my_mutex);
    } else if (strcmp(command, "spinlock_irq") == 0) {
        spin_lock_irqsave(&my_spinlock, irq_disabled);
    } else if (strcmp(command, "spinlock") == 0) {
        spin_lock(&my_spinlock);
    } else if (strcmp(command, "spinunlock") == 0) {
        spin_unlock(&my_spinlock);
    } else if (strcmp(command, "spinunlock_irq") == 0) {
        spin_unlock_irqrestore(&my_spinlock, irq_disabled);
    }
}

// Sysfs attribute for command execution
static ssize_t command_store(struct kobject *kobj, struct kobj_attribute *attr, const char __user *buf, size_t count) {
    if (count > COMMAND_BUF_SIZE)
        return -EINVAL;

    memset(command_buf, 0, COMMAND_BUF_SIZE);

    pr_info ("caling copy_from_user, count=%d\n",count);
    if (copy_from_user(command_buf, buf, count))
        return -EFAULT;

    command_buf[count] = '\0';
    pr_info("Command received : %s\n", command_buf);
    execute_command(command_buf);

    return count;
}

static struct kobj_attribute command_attr = __ATTR(command, 0664, NULL, command_store);

static struct attribute *attrs[] = {
    &command_attr.attr,
    NULL,
};

static struct attribute_group attr_group = {
    .attrs = attrs,
};

static struct kobject *my_kobj;

static int __init my_module_init(void) {
    int result;

    pr_info("Module loaded\n");

    my_kobj = kobject_create_and_add(MODULE_NAME, kernel_kobj);
    if (!my_kobj)
        return -ENOMEM;

    pr_info("calling sysfs_create_group\n");
    result = sysfs_create_group(my_kobj, &attr_group);
    if (result)
        kobject_put(my_kobj);

    return result;
}

static void __exit my_module_exit(void) {
    kobject_put(my_kobj);
}
```

The module gets loaded successfully, but when I write a command, it fails with error :

```
# insmod /locking.ko
[   30.260289] Module loaded
[   30.261227] calling sysfs_create_group
#
#
# cd /sys/kernel/lock_injection/
# echo lock_mutex > command
[   57.351275] caling copy_from_user, count=11
sh: write error: Bad address
#
```

What could be going wrong here ?
This is vanilla `6.5.0` kernel run on QEMU aarch64 `qemu-system-aarch64 -smp 4 -m 2G -machine virt -cpu cortex-a57 ...`.

Comment: `show` and `store` methods of `kobj_attribute` structure doesn't accept user space pointers. You could easily find that by inspecting declaration of these fields in [include/linux/kobject.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/kobject.h#L139): these declarations doesn't contain `__user` modifier. The `buf` parameter to that functions is allocated by the kernel.

Comment: Besides that, you can use better APIs, e.g., `ATTR_RW()`, `__ATRIBUTE_GROUPS()`,`sysfs_streq()`, ... After moving to the proper buffer type, you can drop unneeded `memset()` and NULification of the string (it's done already by kernelfs code.

Comment: Also you must unlock any locks you locked before returning to userspace.